# Alphabetizing the names in SQL

Tags: java, oracle, sorting, sql-order-by, uppercase

I have list of names which needs to be sorted in alphabetical order, So i am doing the UPPER on all values and ORDER_BY to display the sort.

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put( "ORDER_BY", "UPPER (VALUE)" );
ArrayList<DataObject> results = (ArrayList<DataObject>) dao.getDataObjects( params, conn );
```

Sorting works perfectly fine but i am would like to more about the below scenario. Example when i sort for name JaCoBsOn, JACOBson. JACOBson will be first and JaCoBsOn is the next, why not JaCoBsOn first and later JACOBson ??

My guess is because it is converting names to UPPER case. So while sorting names JaCoBsOn and JACOBson is treated as JACOBSON and displays in random order ?

Comment: Your guess is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you convert to uppercase you're getting ties for names like `JaCoBsOn` and `JACOBson`, and yes: Oracle will arrange the ties in (seemingly) random order. To get rid of this randomness you need a tie-breaker.

Note that uppercase sorts before lowercase, so if you want `JaCoBsOn` to sort before `JACOBson` as a tie-breaker you can do something like this:

```
ORDER BY UPPER(VALUE), VALUE DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your guess is right. IMO, which JACOBSON row is placed first depends on the actual row order within the database.